# APIs to get the list of possible routes for iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit

I need to show list of possible routes before displaying it on the Map. I am creating IOS application for IOS 5 and IOS 6. Is there any API available that will respond the possible route for given source and destination location. Please suggest.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Please give the answers of my questions so that I can accept them.

Answer (score 1):

Its depends on Travel Modes:

Like :

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&sensor=false

This responds JSON response that can be easily parse in ios.